# iOS: MKMapView spins on load

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I have a simple map view just showing the user's current location.  My problem is that the map will spin around as if it is trying to figure out which way is North when it loads.  It will also zoom in and out when loading itself.  It does eventually come to a stop and look good, but I want to get rid of this beginning spinning and jerking around.  Is there something that I can add to fix this problem?

**Map Code:**

in view did load:

```
self.mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;
self.mapView.delegate = self;
[self.mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeHybrid];
[self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:YES];
```

and also I have this method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region =  MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 500, 500);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used,

```
[self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:YES]; // notice animated is yes
```

Put No in animated,

```
[self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:NO];
```

Comment: The map still rotates as if it is trying to find which direction it should be facing.  Are there any other methods or properties that I can use to set it to not rotate?